# Create JSON object literal only if value is not null

Tags: python, json, dataframe

I wrote a script which updates some fields in a database via an API.

```
        fields = [{
              "fieldId": "101",                                       
              "fieldValues": [{"value": df["A"].item()}]},
                {   
              "fieldId": "102",                                       
              "fieldValues": [{"value": df["B"].item()}]},
                {   
              "fieldId": "103",                                        
              "fieldValues": [{"value": df["C"].item()}]},
                {   
              "fieldId": "104",                                        
              "fieldValues": [{"value": df["D"].item()}]},
                {   
              "fieldId": "105",                                        
              "fieldValues": [{"value": df["E"].item()}]
              }]
```

Afterwards I do something like `update = update_object(fields = fields)` to update the fields
I'd like to create `fields` more dynamically, meaning that a specific fieldId/fieldValues is only part of `fields` if (e.g.) df["E"] is not null.

How can I realize that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[42, None]], columns=['A', 'B'])
print(df)
```

prints

```
     A     B
0   42  None
```

and then

```
id_key_pairs = [
    ('101', 'A'),
    ('102', 'B')
]

fields = [
    {
        'fieldId': field_id,
        'fieldValues': [{'value': df[k].item()}]
    } for field_id, k in id_key_pairs if df[k].item() is not None
]
print(fields)
```

prints

```
[{'fieldId': '101', 'fieldValues': [{'value': 42}]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a nice case for a list comprehension! In your case, you could use something like this:

```
df_key_map = {101: “A”, 102: “B”, (etc…)}
fields = [
  {
    “fieldId”: id,
    “fieldValues”: [{“value”: df[key].item()}]
  }
  for id, key in df_key_map.items()
  if df[key].item() is not None

]
```